# Is there a way to highlight text inserted since the last commit in IntelliJ in the Editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm talking about getting the same effect you get when you commit/merge/diff and are reviewing your changes.

I would like to have code I added to be highlighted. Right now if you go under VCS, Editor Gutter and VCS annotations, both of them have Foreground disabled. I was wondering if there was a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without an additional plugin (see the other answer). With any plugins, your current VCS changes are shown with markers in the gutter.

Comment: Has this type of feature been requested before?

Comment: Nope, at least I could not find one in the tracker. You are welcome to submit one at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. If you do, please describe the use case you have

Comment: Here it is: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398 I'd very much like that feature!

Answer (score 2):

There is an IntelliJ plugin called [Git Scope](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope) that provides the functionality you are looking for.

You can install it by going to Settings > Plugin > Marketplace and searching for "Git Scope".

Comment: There's a plugin for JetBrains' IDEs:  [Git Scope](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope)

Comment: That's the same one. I also use it!